# Activating a perceptron with the step function

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, neural-networks

Suppose we have a perceptron with input neurons $x$ and weights $w$ and a threshold $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$

The activation function is the step function

$$a_{\epsilon}= \text{if} \ x > \epsilon \ \text{then} \ \text{else} \ 0$$

To activate the perceptron

$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_iw_i > \epsilon$$

Now when we have two perceptrons $p_1 =(x,w,\epsilon_1)$ and $p_2=(x,\tilde w,\epsilon_2)$ with $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \in \mathbb{R}$

I want to show that $p_2$ is activated iff $p_1$ is activated $\forall\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$

$$p_1 =(x,w,\delta_1)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iw_i > \epsilon_1$$

$$p_2 =(x,w,\delta_1)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\tilde w_i > \epsilon_2$$

But I don't know how the show the equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

I would say they can only be equivalent if all the weights and threshold are the same, because you can consider the edge cases where all $x_i=0$ (and thus you need  $\epsilon_1= \epsilon_2$), and all cases where $x_i = 1$ and $x_j=0$ for all $0 \le i \le n$ and $j \not = i$ (from which it will follow that $w_i = \tilde w_i$)

Just conceptually: the perceptron draws a $n$-dimensional hyperplane through the $n+1$-dimensional feature space, and for the two perceptrons to be equivalent, those hyperplanes must be exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you that helped me a lot, but do you mean $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2$ instead of $$\epsilon_1=\epsilon_1$$ in the second line of your answer?

Comment: @Anil Right, of course